# Java Spring Boot app startup fail - ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm try starting java spring boot app but I'm get error.

Java 8.x, Maven Project, Intellij idea community edition on Windows 10

Error detail:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
2018-09-08 13:49:06.496 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@65d6b83b has been closed already
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.getTargetBean(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:283)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
```

Comment: which Spring Boot version do you use? Could you please post your `pom.xml` and your `application.properties` file and provide us some more information about your use case

Comment: please share your config file code and more explain about project